# Is there a way to render a FontAwesome Icon as the background?

Tags: css

For example, I have a div, and some text content inside of it, like this:

```
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eu sapien
    sed massa placerat rutrum. In tristique purus eget porta pharetra.</div>
```

Now I want to add an icon from FontAwesome into the background, like this:

[image]

Notice that, I'd like the div to "crop" the icon a little bit, which I failed to do. Because when the icon is displayed as a block, you cannot crop it by using `overflow: hidden`.

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect?

Comment: You are missing red, hand-drawn circles =(.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using relative and absolute positions.

Here is a rough example to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/n57uf/1/

```
<div class="parent">
    <i class="icon-star-empty icon-4x child"></i>
    <p class="content">Lorum ipsum lorum ipsum etc tect</p>
 <div>

.parent {
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: -20px;
}

.content {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16pt;
}
```

Comment: Note that you still need to float both children in order to make them overlap correctly. The reason I use float instead of `position: absolute` is that in my case the parent `div` itself is a float object, and if you use absolute position then `top` and `left` will refer to a more remote parent.

Answer (score 3):

you can try the following code inside any div.
It will not interfere with other elements.

```
<i class="fa fa fa-microchip fa-10x" style="color: white;position: absolute;right: 10px;top: 10px;opacity: 0.3;"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</div>
</div>
```

and float both children to the left, and set them to have negative margins.

**Update:** Awww ... Jason beat me to it.

Comment: Malformed HTML `</icon>` should be `</i>`